# Почтовые станции — ямы

Tags: этимология

Почему раньше почтовые станции назывались ямами и какая связь у этого названия с ямами в значении "овраг", "углубление"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, никакой связи.

Ям (яма) - почтовая станция или поселок с почтовой станцией, где проезжающие меняли лошадей- от тюрк. jam - дорога.
ЯМА -углубление, вырытое или образовавшееся в земле - общеславянское слово.  Родственно греч. amē "лопата, мотыга". Буквально яма — "вырытое, выкопанное лопатой, мотыгой".

Comment: Отсюда, наверное, и ямщик?

Answer (score 1):

Раньше почтовые станции ставились в местах переправ (чаще всего у рек, речушек). Слово "ям/jam" связано с переправой и одновременно с преградой, для преодоления которой она устраивалась.