# Яма, ям и ямщик

Tags: этимология

Известно, что слово "ямщик" происходит от слова "ям" (или все-таки яма?) - так называли почтовые станции, между которыми они, собственно, и курсировали.
А вот почему сами станции так называются? Имеют ли они что-то общее со словом "яма" в значении "канава", "рытвина" или просто созвучно?
Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите ответ (если есть подходящий), а то его Community будет на главную постоянно выводить как неотвеченный.

Answer (score 2):

Такой вопрос был, на него коротко и точно ответила Ларф:

https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/8512/178412

А вот объяснение Семёнова: ЯМА-Общеславянское – jama.
Индоевропейское – iam (копать, рыть).

Древнерусское слово «яма» вошло в обиход с начала XI в. со значением «ров».
Первоначальный источник – общеславянское jama – имеет индоевропейский корень. Примерно с XIII в. оно использовалось со значением «общая могила», с XV в. – «подземная тюрьма». В современном русском языке слово имеет более обобщенное лексическое значение – «вырытое или образовавшееся в земле углубление».
Слово широко представлено в славянских языках.
Родственными являются:
Украинское, белорусское, болгарское – яма.
Польское – jama (яма, нора, берлога).
Производное: ямка, ямочка.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text15/032.htm

ЯМЩИК
Древнерусское – ямъщикъ.
Тюркское – jam (почтовая станция, почтовая лошадь).
Из всех славянских слово «ямщик» характерно для русского языка. В других языках оно либо отсутствует вовсе, либо употребляется с другим значением.

По своему происхождению слово является достаточно древним. Оно стало широко употребительным уже в XIV в.

Слово было образовано от основы «ям», имевшей сначала значение «повинность», а затем – «стан на дороге, где происходит смена лошадей». Слово «ям» – тюркское, хотя в современных тюркских языках не употребляется.

Ямщиками в России когда-то давно называли княжеских чиновников, следивших за порядком отбывания разного рода повинностей. Позже (ближе к XIX в.) ямщик – «возница на почтовых лошадях, выделенный станцией».
В современном русском языке слово «ямщик» является малоупотребительным и практически перешло в разряд исторической лексики.

Родственным является:
Украинское – ямщик (возница на лошадях).

Answer (score 0):

Ямега
ямега я́мега "шов в полушубке или рыболовных сетях", арханг., олонецк., я́мяга – то же, каргопольск. (Кулик.), я́межить, я́мовить "сшивать две сети в одну", олонецк. (Кулик.). Из карельск. jаmе, род. п. jamien, фин. jаmа, jаmо, jame "соединение, связь", эст. jama "место соединения", карельск. jamuo "сшивать сети", фин. jаmаtа, jаmоа, эст. jamama – то же; см. Калима 251; Лесков, ЖСт., 1892, вып. 4, стр. 103. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

ямщик ямщи́к род. п. -а́, др.-русск. ямьщикъ (грам. 1356, 1365, 1402 гг.; см. Срезн. III, 1659, также у Котошихина 124). Из тюрк. (ср. тур. jamčy "ямщик", чагат. jamči – то же (Радлов 3, 311); см. Мi. ТЕl. I, 315; Бернекер I, 444), сближено вторично с образованиями на -ик. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Ямдать
ямдать я́мдать "кочевать, менять место пастбища оленей", перея́мдать, съя́мдать, мезенск. (Даль, Подв.) Из ненец. jamda(ś) "переселяться". Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Comment: Даже из Фасмера можно сделать вывод, что слово "ямщик" имеет весьма опосредованное отношение к татарам. "Ям" как "связь" могло быть заимствовано из фино-угорских языков. Соответственно, "ямщик" как "связной", "посыльный" - могло быть образовано по правилам русского языка, и уже оттуда - заимствоваться татарами.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Емь
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кингисепп

Comment: Еще нашел   МЧАТЬ, Мчаться.

ямо я́мо "куда", цслав., также амо, аможе, русск.-цслав. ɪамо, ɪамо же ὅπου (Остром. и др.; см. Срезн. III, 1657 и сл.), болг. амо "сюда" (Дювернуа), сербохорв. а̑мо – то же, др.-чеш. jam, jаmžе, jamto, чеш. диал. jamo "куда". Связано с и.-е. местоим. е/о-; см. яко. Образование аналогично тамо – от тъ и камо "куда" – от къто; см. Бернекер I, 417 и сл.; Преобр. I, 262. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973
Share on vkShare on facebookShare on livejournalShare on twitterShare on favoritesShare on email|More Sharing ServicesЕщё

Answer (score 0):

Наряду с Яма — гумно, впадина (Пск. с. г. 1467 г.), а также Ямъ — стан на дороге для перемены лошадей, в ПЦС словаре есть статья о

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

откуда можно полагать, что значение слова *Яма* — придорожный гостевой двор.